# SQL Server : join only one table

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

Let's say that I have those four tables.

**PEOPOLE**

```
ID NAME     SURNAME  COMPANY   UNIT   GROUPS
--------------------------------------------   
1  Michael  Backer      1        1      1
2  Travis   Morgan      2        2      2 
3  George   Marshall    3        3      3
```

**COMPANY**

```
ID NAME
------------
1  Coca Cola
2  Pepsi
3  Sprite
```

**WORKUNIT**

```
ID NAME
-------------    
1  Finances
2  Marketing
3  Sales
```

**GROUPS** (both values can be null)

```
ID NAME          FLOOR
-------------------------  
 1 Risks           5
 2 NULL           NULL
 3 Secretariat    NULL
```

**Expected results**

```
NAME SURNAME COMPANYNAME WORKUNIT GROUPS FLOOR
-----------------------------------------------    
Michael Backer Coca Cola Finances  Risks  5
Travis  Morgan Pepsi Marketing NULL NULL
George Marshall Sprite Sales Secretariat NULL
```

So far I write this query with no success:

```
SELECT
    people.NAME, people.SURNAME, company.NAME,
    workunit.NAME, groups.NAME, groups.FLOOR
FROM
    company, workunit, groups, people
LEFT JOIN
    groups on people.GROUP = GROUPS.id
WHERE
    company.id = people.company AND
    workunit.id = people.unit AND
    groups.id = people.group AND
    groups.floor = 'something from textbox';
```

I am not familiar with combining join statements in more than one table, so please help me out because I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Just write like this:**

```
SELECT 
  people.NAME,
  people.SURNAME,
  company.NAME,
  workunit.NAME,
  groups.NAME, 
  groups.FLOOR
FROM 
  people
  INNER JOIN GROUP
    ON people.GROUP=GROUPS.id
  INNER JOIN company
    ON people.company=company.id
  INNER JOIN UNIT 
    ON people.UNIT =UNIT.id
WHERE
  GROUPS.floor='something from textbox';
```

Comment: The point is that specifying the join criteria in the join clause and not in the where clause is the right way to do things in SQL Server syntax. Leaving the join criteria for the where clause is not only a very old style (1992 and older), but will often result in cartesian products, which much be avoided at all costs. This is not news and there no excuse these days for writing queries using the old syntax. http://www.scarydba.com/2009/09/15/no-join-predicate/

Answer (score 0):

I verified your query in SQL Server. You need to modify it a little bit, at least, to see it executing, in this way:

```
SELECT
    people.NAME, people.SURNAME, company.NAME,
    workunit.NAME, groups.NAME, groups.FLOOR
FROM
    company, workunit, people
LEFT JOIN
    groups on people.GROUP = GROUPS.id
WHERE
    company.id = people.company AND
    workunit.id = people.unit AND
    groups.id = people.group AND
    groups.floor = 'something from textbox';
```

Anyway, your query doesn't work because, even if you want the results in the way you described using a `LEFT JOIN`, you are setting the condition:

```
AND groups.floor = 'something from textbox';
```

In this way, you won't be able to see the records where there isn't a match with the `GROUPS` table, because you're saying explicitly that you want the records where the value of the column `floor` must be equal to `'something from textbox'`.

If you want also the non-matches you can replace the condition with:

```
OR groups.floor = 'something from textbox';
```

but you will have some duplicates and a `group by` statement won't work anyway.
Then, you have to check if you really want those expected results.

I didn't understand why you want also the non-matches, even if you are looking for the precise result, using `groups.floor = 'something from textbox'`. If you want to display the results in a GUI, the non-matches would be useless information for a user, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT people.NAME, people.SURNAME, company.NAME, workunit.NAME, groups.NAME, groups.FLOOR

FROM company, workunit, groups LEFT JOIN  people on people.GROUP=GROUPS.id

WHERE

company.id=people.company AND
workunit.id=people.unit AND
groups.id=people.group AND
groups.floor='something from textbox';
```

Comment: In some cases, I get duplicate results and also I did not get all results (missing those, where GROUP.NAME is null I think).

Comment: It all depends on your criteria I just gave you the inner join and what condition you want to display its your choice.